# angular 7 observable array filtering error

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular7

I am a newbie to Angular. Currently using Angular 7 version. I am trying to do filter operation using filter() method from Observable.
I have created a service to inject Httpclient to load the data form a json file.
Data is getting loaded from json. Now I am trying to filter the data based on EventEmitter.

I am getting filter is not a function error

**country-load.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import 'rxjs';
import { ArrayType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';

/* interface ServerData {
  shows: Show[];
} */


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountryLoadService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient ) {}


  // HTTP get operation to fetch the port data from static JSON
fetchCountry(){
  return this.http.get("assets/data/port_data.json").pipe(map((res) => of(res)));
}
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryLoadService } from './../country-load.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ArrayType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/toArray';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  //@Input() result:string="";
  @Output() changed = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private countryLoadService : CountryLoadService) {}

  countryData;

  ngOnInit() {
  this.countryLoadService.fetchCountry().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.countryData);
    this.countryData = data;
    console.log(this.countryData);
  })

  }

  onChange(countryName:string){
    this.changed.emit(countryName);
  }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
      height="8">
      <tr>
        <td width="70%" align="left" valign="middle" class="toplinks">
          <app-menutab></app-menutab>
        </td>

        <td width="5%" align="right" valign="middle" class="toplinks">
          <label class="toplinks">Load Country</label>
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="right" valign="middle" class="toplinks">
          <select #input1 style="width: 135px; font-family: Arial narrow; font-size: 8pt"
          name="countryCode" (change)="onChange(input1.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let cn of (countryData | async)">{{cn.country_name}}</option>
          <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="countryData[index]" placeholder="item"> -->
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**create-tariff.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryLoadService } from './../country-load.service';
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from,
  interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { ArrayType } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { map, startWith, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs';
import { Country } from './Country'
import { concat } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/concat';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-tariff',
  templateUrl: './create-tariff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-tariff.component.css']
})


export class CreateTariffComponent implements OnInit {

  //jsonData : Observable<any>[] = [];
  //jsonData : Country[] = [];
  jsonData;

  constructor(private currencyLoadService : CountryLoadService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currencyLoadService.fetchCountry().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(typeof(data));
      this.jsonData = data;
      //this.jsonData = Object.entries(data).map(([type, value]) => ({type, value}));
      console.log(this.jsonData);
    })

    }
  onChanged(value:string){
    if(value!='')
    {
      console.log('foo1111');
      console.log(this.jsonData);
      this.jsonData = this.jsonData.filter(res =>res.country_name.startsWith(value));
      //this.jsonData = this.jsonData.map(resp => resp.filter(res => res.country_name.startsWith(value)));
      //const source = from(this.jsonData);
      //const ex = source.pipe(filter(res => res.country_name.starstWith(value)));
      }
      else{
        this.currencyLoadService.fetchCountry().subscribe(
            (data => {
              this.jsonData = data;})
          );
      }
  }

}
```

**create-tariff.component.html**

```
<app-header (changed)="onChanged($event)"></app-header>
        <span *ngFor="let item of (jsonData | async)">{{item.currency}}</span>
```

**port_data.json**

```
[
    {
        "country_name": "Germany",
        "load_port": [
            "DEBRV06",
            "DEBRVTM",
            "DEHAMCA",
            "DEHAMEK"
        ],
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    {
        "country_name": "Denmark",
        "load_port": [
            "DKAARPT",
            "DKCPHTM"
        ],
        "currency": "DKK"
    },
    {
        "country_name": "China",
        "load_port": [
            "CNIWNCT",
            "CNIWNMC",
            "CNNANCT",
            "CNNPOYD"
        ],
        "currency": "CNY"
    }
]
```

When try to do a filtering based on the value received from EventEmitter I am getting the below error.

I have tried different option gathered from internet but no luck till now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
ERROR TypeError: this.jsonData.filter is not a function
    at CreateTariffComponent.push../src/app/create-tariff/create-tariff.component.ts.CreateTariffComponent.onChanged (create-tariff.component.ts:40)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (CreateTariffComponent.html:3)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19628)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20425)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:17077)
    at core.js:18567
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:10250)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
```

**Edit 1**
Please see the console log what I am getting for this json data

```
Observable {_isScalar: true, _subscribe: ƒ, value: Array(3)}
value: Array(3)
0: {country_name: "Germany", load_port: Array(4), currency: "EUR"}
1: {country_name: "Denmark", load_port: Array(2), currency: "DKK"}
2: {country_name: "China", load_port: Array(4), currency: "CNY"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
_isScalar: true
_subscribe: ƒ (subscriber)
__proto__: Object
```

**Edit 2** 
This is what I am getting in console when doing toPromise()

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: Array(3)
0: {country_name: "Germany", load_port: Array(4), currency: "EUR"}
1: {country_name: "Denmark", load_port: Array(2), currency: "DKK"}
2: {country_name: "China", load_port: Array(4), currency: "CNY"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: need to see this in stackblitz. It appears the data you return from your AJAX service is returning an array of streams rather than a stream itself that you can call `map` on. But that is a guess without seeing this in a debugger.

Comment: U sure that u get response from the http.get?
ur http missing .subscribe after the pipe.

Comment: Initialize jsonData = [] . Since it is undefined when angular run ngOnChange first time.

Comment: Tried jsonData = [];
Getting [ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}' error >> 
this.jsonData = this.jsonData.filter(res =>res.country_name.startsWith(value));

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [ { "country_name": "Germany", "load_port": [ "DEBRV06", "DEBRVTM", "DEHAMCA", "DEHAMEK" ], "currency": "EUR" }, { "country_name": "Denmark", "load_port": [ "DKAARPT", "DKCPHTM" ], "currency": "DKK" }, { "country_name": "China", "load_port": [ "CNIWNCT", "CNIWNMC", "CNNANCT", "CNNPOYD" ], "currency": "CNY" } ];


value = "Germany";

var jsonData = data.filter(res =>res.country_name.startsWith(value));

console.log(jsonData)
```

Looks pretty good to me.
try to understand if the data u send is actully ARRAY of Objects and not a string or something else.

Ok like I thought, your get request is not correct.

```
fetchCountry(){
  return this.http.get("assets/data/port_data.json").toPromise().then(d=>d);
}
```

and when you recive on the header component:

```
this.countryData = this.countryLoadService.fetchCountry();
```

Comment: I have updated the question above and share the console log for Observable array

Comment: As per your comment I have tried to use toPromise(). But getting below error.


TypeError: this.currencyLoadService.fetchCountry(...).subscribe

Comment: you changed the way u recived the data? becouse its not longer observable it becomes a promise.

Comment: Can you please give me an example as I am pretty new to this

Comment: I have tried this. Then I am getting the below error in *ngfor.

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Promise]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: when you console.log this,countryData what do u get?

Comment: Please check Edit 2 section in the question. I am getting an ZoneAwarePromise.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `this` is incorrect inside `onChanged`. It gets compiled well somehow but in runtime it might be not what you expect, probably something like `MapSubscriber`.